# Can't set breakpoint in QT Creator when debugging with CDB while processing is running

Tags: qt, qt-creator, windbg

I am not able to set breakpoint in my program when debugging with CDB while the process is running. When I made a click on the left of the source line to set the break point, I got a red breakpoint with a busy status indicator on top of it. The busy indicator never goes away as expected. If I set a breakpoint prior to starting debugging, they will be applied successfully.

If I select Debug->interrupt from the menu while the process is running, QT Creator is not able to pause the process either. Therefore, I believe the cause of the problem is that QTC is not able to pause the process and apply the breakpoint.

If I use GDB, everything is fine. But I don't like to use GDB due to its much slower compiling speed.

Comment: If you have a problem with "compiling speed", you can use [precompiled headers](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-precompiledheaders.html) to speed up the compilation.

Comment: The precompiled header option is already on. But I doubt GDB ever makes use of the precompiler header technology properly. The total compiling time of GDB is four times the time taken by VC compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you have the debugging tools for windows installed on your machine.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009

Check if CDB finds the microsoft symbols.

Go to Tools >> Options >> Debugger

Check if the following path is present in Symbol Paths Text field:

C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows (x64)
symsrv*symsrv.dll*C:\Users\vish6025\AppData\Local\Temp\symbolcache*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

If it's your operating system is 32 bit, You point it to

C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already have CDB debugger installed and symbol path set correctly.